# I2C devices on docker container

Tags: i2c, docker

I am running a docker container on Raspberry Pi 3 and I am trying to read from an I2C device from the container. When I use `i2cdetect` inside docker I can see the devices. The run option I use is `sudo docker run --device /dev/i2c-1  --name <name> <image>`, but when I try to read from the I2C device all CRC checks fail as if the file `/dev/i2c-1` didn't mount correctly. It looks like the directory has just been copied on run and did not bind. Has anyone else experienced this?

I have also tried the `--privileged` option and binding the folder `-v -v /dev:/dev`.

I can't use `i2cget` to test the device because it uses 16bit addressing

I use the wiringPi library for C https://github.com/WiringPi/WiringPi.

On run I get these messages:

```
backup:x:34:34:backup:/var/backups:/usr/sbin/nologin
list:x:38:38:Mailing List Manager:/var/list:/usr/sbin/nologin
irc:x:39:39:ircd:/var/run/ircd:/usr/sbin/nologin
gnats:x:41:41:Gnats Bug-Reporting System (admin):/var/lib/gnats:/usr/sbin/nologin
nobody:x:65534:65534:nobody:/nonexistent:/usr/sbin/nologin
systemd-timesync:x:100:103:systemd Time Synchronization,,,:/run/systemd:/bin/false
systemd-network:x:101:104:systemd Network Management,,,:/run/systemd/netif:/bin/false
systemd-resolve:x:102:105:systemd Resolver,,,:/run/systemd/resolve:/bin/false
systemd-bus-proxy:x:103:106:systemd Bus Proxy,,,:/run/systemd:/bin/false
_apt:x:104:65534::/nonexistent:/bin/false
```

Output from `i2cdetect -y 1` in docker:

```
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 68 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
70: 70 -- -- -- -- -- -- --
```

Comment: Could you add some relevant info? Like the output of `i2cdetect` inside docker, and then errors when you read (can't you use `i2cget` to begin and eliminate yet another unknown - your software).

Comment: 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f

00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 

10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 

20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 

30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 

40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 

50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 

60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 68 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 

70: 70 -- -- -- -- -- -- --

this is the output from docker with i2cdetect -y 1,
I can't use i2cget to test the device because it uses 16bit addressing

Comment: Edit your original post with additional info.

Comment: I don't think binding `/dev` is going to be useful.  Bind mounts as far as I've noticed are about *storage*, but `/dev/` is not that (it's not actually on the SD card either -- I would have guessed you'd end up with an empty directory, with possibly some dud in-name-only copies that ended up that at some point).  OTOH, some quick googling implied it might work at least for some things... Although another possibility is that the bound mount is actually hidden behind a subsequently mounted devtmpfs in the container.